# Security of Visual Studio Marketplace?

Tags: trojan

As a consumer of Visual Studio Marketplace extensions, I frequently find myself wondering if this or that nice little add-on might be a security problem. For example, maybe it uploads my code somewhere. Is this a risk I simply have to take? Is this somehow checked? In the case of a popular add-on, would it be reasonable to assume that if it did do something like that, someone would have noticed?

Answer (score 5):

#### Are Visual Studio Extensions audited?

**No.** Extensions are not audited by default. [This Walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-publishing-a-visual-studio-extension) describes the process of publishing an extension. As can be seen in step 9, the extension can be immediately published after the upload has completed.

#### How can I check what an extension does?

Visual Studio Extensions are delivered in the VSIX format, which is an archive format that can be extracted using 7zip. Technically, it is an [OPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) file [as described here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/anatomy-of-a-vsix-package).

The archive itself contains several files to describe the extension, as well as a .DLL file with the actual code. From there on, you are reverse-engineering a .NET library like any other.

#### Can I trust that other people would do it for me?

Possibly, but you can never be 100% sure. Statistically, it's more likely that an extension that does one tiny thing and has 1 million downloads has been looked at by someone, than an extension that does God-knows-what and has 23 downloads.

However, you then essentially just shift the problem, and ask yourself how much you can trust those random strangers, as opposed to a different set of random strangers.

#### What can I do if I find a malicious extension?

When you look at the Visual Studio Extension Marketplace, you see a report button on the right side of the screen:

[image: Screenshot of the Visual Studio Marketplace]

This is actually a `mailto://` link to the address `vsmarketplace@microsoft.com`, where they ask you to provide a brief description of the issue. I never had to report an extension myself, so I cannot make a statement if any how quickly they would respond to an issue.